# Prime-select doesn't work on Ubuntu18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, power-management, nvidia-prime

So I have both an integrated Intel GPU and a NVIDIA card. I am trying to switch between the two using `prime-select`. I have the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1765363 - `prime-select` doesn't turn off the nvidia card when selecting the intel profile. Indeed, if I run `prime-select intel` and reboot, then `lsmod | grep nvidia` returns nothing indicating that the nvidia drivers aren't loaded. But I still get 25-27W power consumption (by checking `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now`) which means that the Nvidia card is still running.

I am very puzzled because I also have an opposite problem (or maybe it's a feature ;). If I run `prime-select nvidia` and reboot, I now have the following:

```
$lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_drm             49152  1
nvidia_modeset       1110016  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              20361216  13 nvidia_modeset
```

So the nvidia driver is loaded into the kernel. Furthermore:

```
$ prime-select query
nvidia
$ nvidia-smi
Thu Dec 19 00:12:15 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.44       Driver Version: 440.44       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1650    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     2W /  N/A |      1MiB /  3911MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And my power consumption is now only 15W. This is very weird. Basically it appears that even though I selected nvidia profile, the dGPU is not actually running any processes and power is being saved while at the same time the discrete card is available to the system (but apparently not drawing power). Like, this completely puzzles me. Any ideas what's happening with my configuration?

---

ETA: I installed the Nvidia driver from their website. When installing, I added the file `/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf` to blacklist the `nouveau` driver. However, after reading the bug description in the link above, I realized that `prime-select` has to use the `nouveau` driver for the switching so I removed the blacklist file. However, it didn't help with power consumption in the `intel` mode but led to this strange configuration. Does it mean that I am now using the nouveau driver instead of the downloaded Nvidia one? But `nvidia-smi` indicates otherwise.